# What is entailed by a homeomorphism with a discrete metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I have a homework question in which I am asked to prove that several statements are equivalent. I'm confused about a particular step in this chain, namely $a)\implies b)$ below.

---

Given:

Let $M$ be a metric space with metric *d*. Prove that the following are equivalent.

a) $M$ is homeomorphic to $M$ equipped with the discrete metric.

b) Every function $f : M \to M$ is continuous.

c,d,e) etc.

---

Is the metric space in this question always the discrete one, or is the *d* in the original question an arbitrary metric? In a) are both of the treatments of $M$ on the same metric?

Assuming that *d* from the overall premise is not the discrete metric and not both of $M$ in a) are using the discrete metric, what does the homeomorphism from $M$ to $M_{discrete}$ actually entail? Isn't continuity trivial for the discrete metric, and thus of no help in b) when the metric is just *d* again?

Comment: d is not, a priori, equal to a any particular metric.  In a way, yes, I suppose it is a placeholder.  When you are proving a implies b, then you are assuming the (M,d) is homeomorphic to (M,discrete metric), but this is still not the same as assigning an explicit identity to d.  In proving the reverse direction, your goal is to show not that d is equal to something... but only that (M,d) is homeomorphic (i.e., comparable) to (M,discrete metric).

Comment: I didn't  quite understand your question, but let me try to answer based on what I understood:

$(M,d)$ is fixed. $(a) \implies (b)$ means that: "If we know $(M,d)$ is homeomorphic to $(M,\text{discrete})$, does it hold that every function $f: (M,d) \rightarrow (M, d)$ is continuous?

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification. I still get caught up on quantifiers sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose a) holds. I.e. there is some homeomorphism $h$ between $(M,d)$ (where $d$ is just the metric $M$ came with, being a metric space!) and $(M,\rho)$ where $\rho$ is the discrete metric on $M$ ($\rho(x,y) = 1$, except when $x=y$ when it must be $0$).

This means that all subsets of $(M,d)$ are open in the metric topology induced by $d$, because all subsets of $M$ are open in the dicrete metric, or more formally: suppose $A \subset M$, then $h[A]$ is open in $(M,\rho)$, so $A = h^{-1}[h[A]]$ (as $h$ is a bijection!) is open in $(M,d)$ as $h$ is continuous.

Now b) is clear by using the open set definition of continuity.

So $M$ does come with some metric, i.e. for $M$ we just think $(M,d)$ and all questions on its topology are questions on the topology induced by this $d$. Being homeomorphic to the dicrete metric on $M$ then gives us all the info we need on this *topology* on $(M,d)$, which is the only thing needed for continuity.

Comment: After reading your answer I began to wonder: how would every function $f: (M,d) \to \mathbb{R}$ being continuous imply that $(M,d)$ is homeomorphic to $(M, \rho)$? How could we be sure that every subset of $(M,d)$ is open/closed?

Comment: @TaylorRendon If every $f: (M,d) \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, let $A \neq \emptyset$ and define $f(x)=0$ for $x \in A$, $f(x) = 1$ for $x \notin A$. By assumption $f$ is continuous, so $A= f^{-1}[(-\frac 12, \frac12)]$ is open so $A$ is open. Also $A=f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is closed as well. So that follows almost directly from that property.

Comment: That makes sense! However, I didn't think the characteristic function was continuous?

Comment: @TaylorRendon We assume all functions to $\Bbb R$ are continuous, remember? So they are in that situation.

Comment: Wonderful. So given that every function $f : (M,d) \to \mathbb{R}$  is continuous implies that the only metric space $M$ can be is one which every subset is open (and closed), and therefore, homeomorphic to $(M, \rho)$ where $\rho$ is the discrete metric?

Comment: @TaylorRendon yes, precisely.